# Convert filesystem::path into char* on windows

Tags: c++, c++17

The [C++17 filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is based on boost.filesystem.

I am using it on Windows with VS2017 right now.

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

I iterate over a directory

```
for (auto& p: fs::directory_iterator("media"))
```

I want to pass the paths to a function that takes filepaths as `const char *`

I found a similar question about the [boost filesystem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010788/converting-boostfilesystempath-into-char).
A core difference is that the [path in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) is based on a `value_type`.
where

> **value_type**: character type used by the native encoding of the filesystem: char on POSIX, wchar_t on Windows

So what I get is a `const wchar_t *` string.

The following "works" for me:

```
    char file[2000];
    wcstombs(file, p.path().c_str(), 2000);
    auto image = SDL_LoadBMP(file);
```

I am looking for a different version since this implementation is all sorts of messy (decaying array to pointer and _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS).

I am looking for a prettier version that can go straight from path to `const char *` using the new C++17 filesystem on windows.

Here is my SDL2 project that I used to explore this with.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    auto scrrenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    auto images = std::vector<SDL_Surface*>();

    for (auto& p: fs::directory_iterator("media"))
    {
        char file[2000];
        wcstombs(file, p.path().c_str(), 2000);
        auto image = SDL_LoadBMP(file);
        images.push_back(image);
    }

    for (auto&image : images)
    {
        SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, scrrenSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay(2000);
    }

    for (auto&image : images)
        SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
In the comment section there is a simmilar question linked [so-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007437/using-stdfilesystem-output-as-lpcwstr)
That questions is a different manifestation of the same core issue which is converting path to a format that can be consumed by another method. I would argue against deleting this question because of the way both are found with different searches.

Comment: There should be a definition you can use in a header called MAX_PATH.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54007437/560648, potentially?

Comment: Unfortunately, MAX_PATH has the old limit, not the current limit of 32768 UTF-16 encoding units.

Comment: @Eljay this is only partially true. At least [according to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation), one can exceed the `MAX_PATH` limit only for absolute paths with a \\?\ prefix. And even then, the limit will not necessarily be exactly 32768 but a bit less…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel a little further down on that same MSDN page: "*Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.*" So you don't need \\?\ anymore if you opt in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, that's cool, no idea how I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [`*string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) and [`generic_*string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/generic_string) member functions of the [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) object to convert the path into either a native or a generic (i.e., POSIX-style) string. For example:

```
SDL_LoadBMP(p.path().string().c_str());
```

Note that these methods return an `std::basic_string<T>` value. So one must make sure that, e.g., a pointer obtained from calling `.c_str()` directly on the return value—like in the example above—does not outlive the string it points to…

Comment: I tested it and this is what I was looking for... now I need to wait 7 Minutes to accept your answer. :)

Comment: Note that the returned string is a temporary, and therefore will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. This code may be fine assuming SDL doesn't store the pointer for later use, but it should be made clear to future visitors that storing `string().c_str()` for later use won't work.