# C++ - Convert from std::filesystem::path to const char

Tags: c++, path, char

I have this code that creates a `std::filesystem::path` from another existing path:

```
std::filesystem::path outfilename = PathToNewVersionTXT;
```

Is it possible to convert `outfilename` to a `const char*` type?  As that is what is required later down in the code.

Comment: SOLVED BY USING STANDARD C `fopen`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert filesystem::path into char\* on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109159/convert-filesystempath-into-char-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`path::string()` or `path::u8string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) method to get the path as a `std::string`, and then you can use the [`string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path outfilename = PathToNewVersionTXT;
std::string outfilename_str = outfilename.string(); // or outfilename.u8string()
const char *outfilename_ptr = outfilename_str.c_str();
```

Comment: Now I get only 2 errors, both on line 63, line 63 being: ```curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);```

The errors being: `non-standard use of class 'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' as an argument to a variadic function`

as well as 'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: @Techflash that issue has absolutely nothing to do with your question of converting a filename path to a character string. You need to post that issue as a new question. One question per post, please. But, I can tell you right now, you can't pass a `std::ofstream` *by value* to a function parameter. Which is what the error messages are complaining about you doing.

Comment: Platform independency.... Linux: "obj.path().c_str()" works. Windows -> Error. Solution "obj.path().string().c_str()"

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you just need to use `std::filesystem::path::c_str` to get a pointer to the `w_char_t` (windows) or `char` (Linux).

You can’t change it to `const char` Because that’s just a single character and you want multiple characters to make up a pathname. You really want a `const char*` which is what this function returns (Linux).

Comment: Got kinda close: I figured out this:
`const char* outfilenamestr = std::filesystem::path::c_str(outfilename);`

But it still gives an error:
E0245 a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Comment: @Techflash because that syntax is wrong, you would need `const char* outfilenamestr = outfilename.c_str();` instead. Which will work only on Posix systems, but not on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `c_str()` function for this. E.g. `const char* str = path.c_str();`.

Comment: Didn't work:
E0144 a value of type "const std::filesystem::path::value_type *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char *"

Comment: That's probably because value_type* has wchar_t* not char*.

Comment: Try converting it using a std::stringstream.
For example std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << outfilename;
const char* x = sstream.str().c_str()

Comment: That new code just gives me:
no instance of constructor "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ofstream [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" matches the argument list

Comment: Make sure you #include <sstream>

Comment: this works for me:
`std::filesystem::path path("hello");
std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << path;
std::string convertedstr = sstream.str();
const char* ptr = convertedstr.c_str();
// then use a function which accepts the const char*
std::printf(ptr);`

Comment: Just added <sstream>, no difference.

Comment: Like this?

outfilenameNonstr is the filesystem::path,
outfilename is what I want to be the char thing

`std::filesystem::path outfilenameNonstr; std::stringstream sstream; sstream << outfilenameNonstr; std::string outfilename = sstream.str(); const char* ptr = outfilename.c_str();`

Comment: are you sure you're using std::stringstream? you may be using std::ofstream?

Comment: I am using ofstream, is there an issue with that?
Later in the code:
`ofstream fp(outfilename);`

Comment: yes i believe that should work. just make sure the std::string outfilename doesn't go out of scope otherwise `ptr` will be pointing to something which no longer exists

Comment: It sounds like you need to include <fstream> too

Comment: If that should work, why am I getting all of these?
`'std::filesystem::path outfilenameNonstr': redefinition`,
`non-standard use of class 'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' as an argument to a variadic function`,
`'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: These are all of my `#include`s
```#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>```

Comment: those errors are unrelated. you seem to be copying an object of std::ofstream which you can't do

Comment: Maybe the line numbers would give more context:

Error 1: `std::filesystem::path outfilenameNonstr; std::stringstream sstream; sstream << outfilenameNonstr; std::string outfilename = sstream.str(); const char* ptr = outfilename.c_str();` |||||

Error 2 & 3: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);`